# Azure Integration Runtime within managed Virtual Network using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory it is possible to create 3 types of Integration Runtimes using the Portal:

1. Azure
2. Azure-SSIS
3. Self-hosted

But looking at Terraform documentation site for the AzureRM provider it is only possible to create an Azure-SSIS ([azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_managed](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory_integration_runtime_managed)) and self-hosted ([azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_self_hosted](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory_integration_runtime_self_hosted)).

Have anyone successfully created a default Azure IR connected to a virtual network as specified in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/managed-virtual-network-private-endpoint using Terraform?

Answer (score 0):

No, not really, unfortunately AzureRM provider doesn't allow it yet.
Also it can't be done using [Azure CLI for Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/datafactory/datafactory/integration-runtime?view=azure-cli-latest) or similar.

Main reason may be the public-preview of [Azure Data Factory Managed Virtual Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/managed-virtual-network-private-endpoint).

What is new though (and part of the solution) is [public_network_enabled](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory#public_network_enabled) property on ADF, you still have to define private endpoint, but that's one step forward.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can see a PR has been submitted to the creators to deal with this: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/10236

Answer (score 0):

By default if you are not specifying the Integration runtime resource of data factory from terraform, it picks the Azure (Auto resolve) Runtime by default.